# How to install nginx. Is nginx repos down?

Tags: nginx

I'm following the instructions on how to install nginx here:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/

But no matter what I do I always get:

```
http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/centos/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

My nginx.repo file is like so:

```
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo 
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/centos/7/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
```

I also tried centos 6 and same thing.

So either the instructions are wrong, I'm doing something wrong, or nginx's yum repos are down.

Maybe I have to compile nginx from source as an alternative?

I don't see any mention anywhere on nginx's repos being down:
https://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2024-February/thread.html

Comment: I've now emailed the nginx-devel group, to see if we can get an answer: https://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-devel/2024-February/T6ESHGUGVA2C5IXGYQ6JKCQ3NRZGH7PN.html

Comment: Multiple reports open at Trac as well: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/report/1?sort=ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repos are back up and fix was confirmed on Trac.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the same for Ubuntu, the repos indeed seem to be down:

```
E: The repository 'http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).